# Is CryptUIDlgSelectCertificateFromStore not supported in win32?

Tags: windows, winapi, win32gui

Is `CryptUIDlgSelectCertificateFromStore` not supported in win32 applications ?

I tried to show the list of Certificates from store, but it lists only one certificate and also not let select any other certificate.

Code snippt:

```
HCERTSTORE hCertStore = CertOpenSystemStore(NULL, L"MY");

CryptUIDlgSelectCertificateFromStore(hCertStore, GetForegroundWindow(), L"Select Certificate", L"Select Certificate", CRYPTUI_SELECT_ISSUEDBY_COLUMN| CRYPTUI_SELECT_INTENDEDUSE_COLUMN
        | CRYPTUI_SELECT_LOCATION_COLUMN| CRYPTUI_SELECT_EXPIRATION_COLUMN, 0, NULL);
```

Also click on "more option" it is causing the crash.

Comment: I have tried this code in console project, and it's working for me. One certificate is shown, but there is option "More choices". If I click it the dialog is expanded and I can  select another certificate from the list. Try this code in separate console project. If it works then the problem is in other parts of your code.

Comment: I did notice something else. Those columns options make no difference. Setting zero to fifth function parameter produces the same result. Which makes sense, as there are no "columns" in the dialog. The parameter is maybe a remnant of some old version of the dialog.

Comment: Your code works fine on my PC: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlt67.png. You said it caused a crash. What kind of that? What is the crash specifically.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the visual studio debugger is the culprit here.
When I run the above code using Visual studio more choice throws error :

```
'testApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.Graphics.dll'. 
Exception thrown at 0x7564D8A2 (KernelBase.dll) in testApp.exe: 0x40080202: WinRT transform error (parameters: 0x8000000B, 0x80070490, 0x00000014, 0x02F6C5E4).
Exception thrown at 0x7564D8A2 (KernelBase.dll) in testApp.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80070490 : 'Windows.Graphics.Display: GetForCurrentView must be called on a thread that is associated with a CoreWindow.'.
Exception thrown at 0x7564D8A2 in testApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_error at memory location 0x02F6CF40.

The program '[624] testApp.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Where as if run Application as  independent binary it works !!!

Comment: Good job. You can accept it for a guidance.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct. The reason, as said by Dialecticus, is in other parts. Microsoft supports this win32api, in higher than Windows XP Systems. Refer to:[CryptUIDlgSelectCertificateFromStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/cryptuiapi/nf-cryptuiapi-cryptuidlgselectcertificatefromstore?redirectedfrom=MSDN).